# Rails helper - undefined method `quantity`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to set up a helper to work out how much stock is left after a customer makes a purchase. A customer has some line_items and a product has some stock. So effectively I tried to do the following.

**Method 1**

**helper.rb**

```
module ProductsHelper

  def wtf_stock(product)
    product.stock - product.line_items.quantity.sum
  end
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
    <%= wtf_stock(product) %>
```

This results in the following: `undefined method quantity' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x5380cc8>`

Alternatively commented out the helper `ProductsHelper` and `<%= wtf_stock(product) %>` and added

**Alternative Method**

```
def wtf_stock
    product.stock - product.line_items.quantity
  end
```

to my `product.rb` then tried to call this in my view by doing `<%= product.wtf_stock %>`. Then got the following error `undefined local variable or method product' for #<Product:0x59fbc50>`

What would be the best way to calculate the remaining stock using my `stock` and `quantity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your helper:

```
def wtf_stock(product)
  product.stock - product.line_items.sum(:quantity)
end
```

Call:

```
wtf_stock(product)
```

Or for product.rb (which is better):

```
def wtf_stock
  stock - line_items.sum(:quantity)
end
```

Call:

```
product.wtf_stock
```

Comment: Your better version resulted in a `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error. However your initial answer worked

Comment: Did you put the second method in the Product model?

Comment: Yeah it worked, will accept the answer as soon as it allows me to

Answer (score 0):

```
def wtf_stock
    self.stock - self.line_items.quantity
end
```

use self instead of product.

Comment: This resulted in a argument error `1 for 0`. What is the benefit of using `self` and @Matzi answer worked

Comment: `line_items` is a relation, you need to acces one element to access `quantity`, or call some aggregation function.